# MySQL INSERT into with COUNT() and GROUP BY error `Invalid use of group function`

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to do the following query and get an error that it is an invalid use of group by function.  Any ideas?

```sql
insert into table_a(id, date, product)
select id, date, count(product)
from table_b
group by id, date
on duplicate key update product = count(product)
```

Comment: This would probably be better off as a `VIEW` that you can materialize if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't kow what you try to accomplish, sanatizing query helps only marginaly, but you can't use count( as you notced but you can make a corect SELECT that gives you the desired result.

```
insert into table_a(id, date, product)
select id, date, count(product)
from table_b
group by id, date
on duplicate key update product = 
    (SELECT COUNT(product) FROM table_b WHERE id = VALUES(id)  GROUP BY id, date LIMIt 1) t1
```

This is of course only an example how you can do something leike you want, but of course you have to adept to your needs